# Flutter: How to fetch data from api once and use for different screen

Tags: flutter

How can I fetch data, for example user detail once in one screen and use it in another screen?

I want to fetch the data once and I can use the data in another screen and no need to fetch again.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question you know how to fetch user details, but don't want to load it several times, rather use the data from different widgets.

Shared preferences could work but I don't recommend it, it is meant to store only primitive data.

An easy but not perfect solution is to create an application level singleton-like class. You can load/update user details and it can be accessed from everywhere in your app. Something like:

```
class UserDetails {
   // define every member data here that you will load
   static late String name;
   static late String email;
   
   // this makes it singleton-like
   factory UserDetails() => UserDetails._internal();
   UserDetails._internal();
}
```

You can set / get user details like:

```
UserDetails.name
```

A more Flutter-like approach would be considering user details as a **state** of your app and use **notifiers** to "broadcast" these values throughout your widget tree. A good starting point would be to [read this part in the documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Here is a very simple example how to **load the data from an API and store the data in the singleton class**. The example is restricted to only one data (email) but of course you can extend it. In real world application a lot of error handling would be needed, this example assumes that everything is just fine:

```
class UserDetails {
  static late String email;

  factory UserDetails() => UserDetails._internal();
  UserDetails._internal();

  static Future<void> getUserDetails() async {
    // API_BASE_URL for example: "domain.com"
    // API_URL for example: "/user/details"
    // AUTHORIZATION: optional, skip headers part if you don't need
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.https(API_BASE_URL, API_URL),
        headers: {'authorization': AUTHORIZATION});

    // here we decode the response body, assuming
    // that data is under "data" tag in response JSON
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];

    // and within it we have an "email" tag with the user's mail
    // here 'email' is the static member of this class
    // and we set the value from the API response
    email = responseData["name"];
  }
}
```

**Beware, for simplicity there is no error handling**. We don't even check whether the response has a status code of 200. (You can easily add it, hint: response.statusCode contains it.) Furthermore, other things can go wrong, server outage etc.

Ok, so how to load the data and access it? The function **getUserDetails** is async, so somewhere in your code (somewhere early I guess) you have to call it **once** from another async function so you can await it. Make sure you find a place where it won't run again and check with debug console! The following line will get the data from the API and store it in the static member:

```
await UserDetails.getUserDetails();
```

If this is done, you can read and write the user details loaded from your API, from anywhere in your application, without reloading it:

```
print(UserDetails.email);
UserDetails.email = "new email";
```

Comment: I'm using http to get the data from API. I can also create a singleton-like class to get the data?

Comment: I would rather create a model class that contains all members that your API sends. When you get your data you create a new instance of that class, an object.

Comment: For example it is very usual that an API returns not one data, but a collection, an array. In this case you can convert the result (probably JSON) into a list of objects.

Comment: Check this guide here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data.

Comment: I already have the model class of user detail, what you mean is I create a new class to store the data when I get the data? Because I want to access the data in other widget without calling the api again.

Comment: You asked about singleton class. Singleton classes have only one instance. If that's ok, if you never will need more than one instance, then it is fine.

Comment: Or please clarify your question, maybe I don't understand it.

Comment: Let me rewrite my sentence. Lets say, after the user login, I want to call an API to get the user information. Then I would like to use the data from the API that I called without calling it again when I go to another screen. Is singleton class able to do it? Sorry if my sentence is confusing.

Comment: No problem. But it is your original question, isn't it? Singleton class can store user details and is accessible from different screens as detailed in my answer. Or do you need help on how to call the API and store the results?

Comment: Ya, it's my original question. I think I need help on how to store the data in singleton class when I call the API.

Comment: I will add some code to my original answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package to store the data and retrieve it every time you want to use it.

Comment: Kindly, edit your answer and add a little more information so that it can answer OP's question and help future readers. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Write your API function in other file see below:

```
Future apiCall() async {
  var url = 'put your API url here';
  var result = await http.get(url);
  if (result.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(result.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed');
  }
}
```

> then call your API function in other file when you call the API below:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: apiCall(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {
            return Text(
              
                  '${snapshot.data[0]['name']}'
                  
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                wordSpacing: 200,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
             
            );
          } else {
            return Text(
              '❌ No Data Found',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            );
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this something like below

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;



class Post {
  int? userId;
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? body;

  Post({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}

class PostDetails {
  static int count = 0;
  static late List<Post> posts;

  /// A singleton preference provider.
  ///
  /// Calling it multiple times will return the same instance.
  static Future<void> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      count;
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      posts = parsed.map<Post>((json) {
        return Post.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
}
```

usage in any of your stateful widget will go like this

```
@override
  void initState() {


    super.initState();

    
    loadPostData();
  }

  loadPostData() async {
    await PostDetails.fetchPost();
    print(PostDetails.count);
    PostDetails.posts.forEach((element) {
      print(element.title);
    });

  }
```

but now if you need this call in another widget don't forget now this object is already in memory so just call like below

@override
void initState() {

```
    super.initState();
 
    loadPostData();
  }

  loadPostData() async {
   
    print(PostDetails.count);
    PostDetails.posts.forEach((element) {
      print(element.title);
    });

  }
```

here in above block am not calling please notice the difference

```
await PostDetails.fetchPost();
```